# force variation by plate of parallel plate capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

Now If I consider a parallel plate capacitor connected across a battery then ,

force(f) between the plates should **not** be proportional to distance(d) **(that's what I think)**

as force due to plate on other=$q\sigma/\epsilon_0$
where $\sigma $would be the charge density and q be the charge on other plate.

But my text says it's inversely proportional to distance .
Now what I think is that what I did above may be correct for only an isolated capacitor but given is connected across terminals; If so then how can I derive it mathematically that :
$f\alpha d^-2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the capacitance is proportional to $\frac{1}{d}$. This means that, when the voltage is constant, the charge (and the charge density) will both be proportional to $\frac{1}{d}$.

Can you see it now?

Comment: I see that charge would be proportional $d^-1$ clearly but how come force ?

Comment: Surface charge determines the electric field, Force is the product of charge and electric field - so you should find the force is inversely proportional to the square of the distance. Details of the derivation can be found [here](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~shuman/XENON/REFERENCES&OTHER_MISC/electric_forces.pdf)